# Probability theory, calculating P(B1)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If I know the values for $P(A|B)$, $P(B|A)$, and $P(A^c|B)$

Is it possible to calculate the value for $P(B)$?

Answer (score 0):

**NO**.

---

We have the well known
$$P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$$
Which we rearrange here to get
$$P(B) =\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(A | B)}$$

We thus still have to know $P(A)$.

However, since $P(A^c|B) = 1-P(A|B)$, we actually only know $P(B|A)$ and $P(A|B)$, from which we cannot extract $P(A)$ **in general**